# Arch linux install not showing in grub

Tags: arch-linux

I have installed Arch with Ubuntu and Fedora on same machine. But now Arch Linux is not showing in grub bootloader.

Comment: Can you post the output of `os-prober`, if you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into one of the two others, say Ubuntu, trigger an `update-grub` in there, which should run os-prober, detect all installations, and update the grub-menu with loaders for all of them. If it doesn't, try the same from the Fedora installation.

Comment: Tried from both but didn't work. :(

Comment: what is the output of os-prober?

Comment: I am away from my machine. Will update when I will be back home.